# How to purposely get the Google traffic error?

Tags: google-search

Hi I want to know how to get the google traffic error.

If you don't know what it is, it's basically when you search things too often and then Google redirects you to a site where you have to a CAPTCHA.

Thanks.

Comment: I have never experienced this particular problem and I type more than 120 words a minute with around 98% accuracy.

Comment: Sorry I mean searching too fast.

Comment: I have ran searched within seconds and never had a problem.  Questions about Google Search are out of scope anyways

Comment: Where should I put this question then?

Comment: I by the way it happens when I use autoclicker and press too many buttons.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show hat you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].